# How to include an Array and a Incrementing Variable into a getElementById Statement?

Tags: javascript, arrays, getelementbyid, multi-select, setattribute

I am trying to disable dynamically created drop down menu options (depending on the users interaction with other menus options) and I am running into an error stating that "null" is not an object.

On this Line of code:

```
if (document.getElementById(DropDownNames[j]+x).value = openerVals) {
```

I believe I have a syntax error however I am still very new to Javascript and am not entirely sure.

Here is the entire code:

```
var OpeningEmployees = document.getElementById('opener');
var QuantityDDOptions = ('#opener option').length;

var openerVals = eodForm.elements["opener"].value;

var DropDownNames = new Array();
DropDownNames[0] = "ui-multiselect-opener-option-";
DropDownNames[1] = "ui-multiselect-mid-option-";
DropDownNames[2] = "ui-multiselect-closer-option-";
DropDownNames[3] = "ui-multiselect-SR-option-";
DropDownNames[4] = "ui-multiselect-CR-option-";
DropDownNames[5] = "ui-multiselect-A-option-";
DropDownNames[6] = "ui-multiselect-BD-option-";
DropDownNames[7] = "ui-multiselect-Fridge-option-";
DropDownNames[8] = "ui-multiselect-AO-option-";
DropDownNames[9] = "ui-multiselect-EPV-option-";



OpeningEmployees.onchange = function () {
    for (var j = 0; j <= DropDownNames.length; j++){
        for (var x = 0; x <= QuantityDDOptions; x++) {
        if (document.getElementById(DropDownNames[j]+x).value = openerVals) {
            document.getElementById("'"+DropDownNames[j]+x+"'").setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
```

Thank you all for your help. I have made the changes from your posts and am still getting the error in the browser console. Note that the numbers at the ends of the drop down names are dynamic. As users get added to the database they get added to the drop down menu thats why I set QuantityDDOptions equal to the amount of options. The options start at 0.

Here is the Updated Code:

```
var OpeningEmployees = document.getElementById('opener');
var QuantityDDOptions = ('#opener option').length;

var openerVals = eodForm.elements["opener"].value;

var DropDownNames = new Array();
DropDownNames[0] = "ui-multiselect-opener-option-";
DropDownNames[1] = "ui-multiselect-mid-option-";
DropDownNames[2] = "ui-multiselect-closer-option-";
DropDownNames[3] = "ui-multiselect-SR-option-";
DropDownNames[4] = "ui-multiselect-CR-option-";
DropDownNames[5] = "ui-multiselect-A-option-";
DropDownNames[6] = "ui-multiselect-BD-option-";
DropDownNames[7] = "ui-multiselect-Fridge-option-";
DropDownNames[8] = "ui-multiselect-AO-option-";
DropDownNames[9] = "ui-multiselect-EPV-option-";



OpeningEmployees.onchange = function () {
    for (var j = 0; j < DropDownNames.length; j++){
        for (var x = 0; x < QuantityDDOptions; x++) {
            if (document.getElementById(DropDownNames[j]+x).value == openerVals) {
                document.getElementById(DropDownNames[j]+x).setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
```

Comment: Right before your if statement, put `console.log(DropDownNames[j]+x);`. This will let you see which one it's failing on.

Comment: fails on `ui-multiselect-opener-option-4` probably because ATM there is only 4 options and it is counting option 0 as one of them.

Comment: Ok. So do you know for sure that that element is there? It seems like it should be there if the numbers are based on #opener's length. But I just noticed something that doesn't quite look right. In the second line in your code, it looks like you are using jQuery to get the number of options in #opener, and I think you are missing the `$` or `jQuery` before `('#opener option').length;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
document.getElementById(DropDownNames[j]+x).value = openerVals
```

needs to be

```
document.getElementById(DropDownNames[j]+x).value == openerVals
```

A single `=` will set something equal to another thing (and returns the set value). Since you use this, that means that the result that's used by the `if` statement is the truthyness of the set value.

`==` is used to evaluate if two things are equal to each other, with type coercion. (2 `==` "2" is true)

`===` is used to evaluate if two things are equal to each other, without type coercion. (2 `!==` "2" is true)

Comment: No problem for the edit, I know what you meant, I'm just trying to help express it...and I might add a little :)

Comment: @Ian well much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

That if statement should be using `==` instead of `=`. And in the next line, you don't need to put the quotes around the id. It's already a string.

The reason for getting the error is that you should have

```
for (var j = 0; j < DropDownNames.length; j++){
```

If you use `<=`, you'll be trying to access an array element that isn't there (DropDownNames[10]), so `document.getElementById` won't return anything. This is most likely also the case for `x`.

Comment: Good point about the loop counter, I didn't notice that! And about the extra quotes, of course :)

Comment: Thanks, I do that all the time - copy the code and need to change one character, but forget :)

Comment: Thank you Ian, I made these changes. However I am still getting the same error code. Do you happen to see anything else that I am missing?

Comment: @DarkSpartan47 Don't thank me, thank jonhopkins - it's his answer! Anyways, please post your updated code at the bottom of your original question so we can make sure all things are correct. Are you seeing any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: @DarkSpartan47 do you have `j < DropDownNames.length` and `x < QuantityDDOptions`? And also, are the numbers at the ends of the dropdown names 0 to 9, or 1 to 10?

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement is using assignment (=) instead of comparison (==)

Some people would even say to use === for comparison in javascript